# Making a new instance of a json javascript class?

Tags: javascript, json

I've started writing a lot more javascript lately and am trying to do it all in the best way I can. Formatting my classes using JSON seems to be the cleanest way but I'm having trouble with something that seems like it should be really basic, but I just struggle to find the answer anywhere... perhaps merely from a lack of the right jargon!

So far I've been doing things in this method:

```
function foo(){
   this.bar = 'hello world';
   this.init = function(){
      alert('this.bar');
   }
}

crow = new foo();
crow.init();
```

And that all seems to work as I expect it to. When I lay out the object in JSON though I can't see to create a new instance of it, only a reference to the original which defeats the point of a lot of uses for me. What am I doing wrong here?

```
foo = {
   bar = 'hello world';

   init:   function(){
      alert(bar);
   }

}

foo.bar(); // This alerts 'hello world'

crow = foo ;
crow.bar = 'metal' ;
crow.init(); // Outputs 'metal'
foo.init(); // Also outputs 'metal'
```

Have I missed the point somewhere, is this the wrong approach or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: you aren't creating a new copy, you are copying the reference to `foo`.

Comment: That's not JSON. JSON is a serialization format (i.e. a transport format) for data and as such it always is a string. What you talk about are JavaScript object literals – something that is only visually related to JSON. *(apart from that your second sample is a syntax error and never outputs anything)*

Comment: javaScript by definition does not use classes

Comment: Hi guys. DanielA.White, that's the obvious part of it, but not very helpful!

I realise that it's not classes strictly speaking but still very handy; @Tomalak so are you saying this isn't the way to approach things? If not, what should I be searching for for information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to define the functions in a class as an object you need to alter the prototype of the function. Here is an example from your code:

```
var foo = function() {}
foo.prototype = {
    bar: 'hello world',

    init: function() {
        alert(this.bar);
    }
};

var crow = new foo();
crow.bar = 'metal';
crow.init();
```

While it is essential to understand how this works if you are using javascript, John Resig has a small script that is fantastic for adding [oop features in javascript](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/). This addition allows a psedo-inheritance with the use of a constructor and super functions.

Comment: That looks exactly like what I've been looking for, cheers! Is there any known problems with this approach or is it a fairly standard way of approaching things?

Comment: This is a standard way for making a "class" in javascript. As another poster mentioned, the terminology between class, object and function gets a bit muddled in javascript.

You can use the new keyword to instantiate a function as a "class" object. The prototype of the original function will be available to any instances in its original form and functions can use the `this` keyword to access a reference to the object that initiated the function call. When paramerters are changed using the `this` keyword, only the data in the individual instance is updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) in your project then you can use the [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) method to achieve Object deep copying:

```
var original = { a: 123, b: "xxx" },
    copy = $.extend(true, {}, original);
```

The first input parameter of *true* means that the copy will be deep.

Answer (score 0):

All objects are copied by reference, so by doing

```
crow = foo ;
```

you'll get the reference to the same object. In order to create new object use function:

```
function apply(o, c){
    if(o && c && typeof c == 'object'){
        for(var p in c){
            if (c.hasOwnProperty(p) {
                o[p] = c[p];
            }
        }
    }
    return o;
};
```

than you can use it

```
var crow = apply({}, foo);
```